# How to replace a particular value of a field (column) in a file with a value from another file in shell scripting?

Tags: python, shell

I have two files say A.txt and B.txt. A.txt has three columns which looks like below

```
0 0 17
0 1 17
0 2 4
0 3 50
0 4 90 
....
....
```

I have to replace the third column values with their corresponding map values which are saved in B.txt which looks like below

```
1 1
2 1
3 1
4 1
..
17 5
..
50 8
..
90 11
..
```

The values of the first column in B.txt and the values of the third column in A.txt are the same and I need to create a new file(say C.txt) whose first two columns are the same as that of A.txt but the third column contains the corresponding map values.
Sample of C.txt appears as below

0 0 5,
0 1 5,
0 2 1,
0 3 8,
0 4 11,
...,
...

**NOTE**

I have 400000 files to do this operation so speed matters. I have written a program for this but thats running very slow. If instead of creating new file(C.txt) replacement saves time that solution is also acceptable.

```
while read line
do

     origPhoneme=`echo $line| cut -d " " -f3` 
     while read mapLine
     do
        mapPhone=`echo $mapLine | cut -d " " -f1`
        replacementPhone=`echo $mapLine | cut -d " " -f2`
        if [ $mapPhone == $origPhoneme ]
        then
             echo $replacementPhone >> checkFile
             break
        fi
     done < B.txt
done< A.txt
```

paste -d " " A.txt checkFile > C.txt

By using this code the C.txt file contains the third column of A.txt which I dont want

Comment: Could you post the code that runs slowly?

Comment: "I have 400000 files to do this operation so speed matters."  If you have that many files, speed probably *doesn't* matter: you're probably I/O bound.  (This doesn't apply to sufficiently silly code, I guess, e.g. something which rereads B.txt and does a linear scan for each row of A.  So @StevenRumbalski's suggestion is a good one.)

Comment: I don't know shell scripting, but it looks like you are iterating over each line of `B.txt` for each line of `A.txt`.  This nested looping will be very slow.  I suggest following Tim Pietzcker's answer below, which creates a dictionary (mapping) from `B.txt` for fast lookups.

Comment: the example I have given is just a sample. The files are usually longer. B.txt has 245 lines and A.txt size varies.

Comment: If your files are each sorted on the matching field, then you can use the unix `join` command.  If they are not sorted and if it ok to change the order of lines, then you can use the the unix `sort` command before using `join`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python (or shell scripts) should be fast enough - your task is mainly limited by I/O speed, not processing speed.

So I would suggest a Python approach like this:

Read `B.txt` into a dictionary for fast lookup:

```
with open("B.txt") as file:
    B = dict(line.strip().split() for line in file)
```

Then process `A.txt`, creating `C.txt`:

```
with open("A.txt") as infile, open("C.txt", "w") as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        start, end = line.strip().rsplit(None, 1)
        outfile.write("{0} {1}\n".format(start, B[end]))
```